# How to call a conditional function based on a selected option with a submit button?

Tags: javascript

I want users to randomly generate a combination of letters and numbers by first selecting the order they want them in (number-letter-number, letter-number-letter, etc.) from a drop down select menu and then pressing a submit button to call the function. The function randomly pulls from the array. Then, depending on which option the user selected, combines them in that way and returns it back to the user.

I've worked a similar code before that didn't involve conditionals or a select menu. Instead, it was just a button that users pressed to call the function. The function had two or more arrays which were randomized successfully with `Math.floor ( Math.random() * listOne.length );` After it was randomized, the function would put parts together with a simple `listOne[partOne] + listTwo[partTwo]` setup.

Anyway, this is the basic code that I have right now. It only returns `undefined` to the user. I've never worked with conditionals or select menus before so I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. If you could please explain and provide me with a solution, I would be eternally grateful.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function myFunction()
{
var x=document.getElementById("result");
var listOne = Array();
var listTwo = Array();
var number = Math.floor ( Math.random() * listOne.length ); 
var letter = Math.floor ( Math.random() * listTwo.length );

listOne[0] = "1";
listOne[1] = "2";
listOne[2] = "3";

listTwo[0] = "A";
listTwo[1] = "B";
listTwo[2] = "C";

var select = document.getElementById("mySelect");
var order = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;

x.innerHTML = Result

if (order === 1)
{var Result = listOne[number] + listTwo[letter] + listOne[number];}

if (order === 2)
{var Result = listTwo[letter] + listOne[number] + listTwo[letter];}

if (order === 3)
{var Result = listOne[number] + listTwo[letter] + listTwo[letter];}

if (order === 4)
{var Result = listTwo[letter] + listOne[number] + listOne[number];}

if (order === 5)
{var Result = listOne[number] + listOne[number] + listTwo[letter];}

if (order === 6)
{var Result = listTwo[letter] + listTwo[letter] + listOne[number];}

}
</script>



<div id="result"><i>Your result will appear here</i></div>

<select id=mySelect>
 <option value="1">one</option>
 <option value="2">two</option>
 <option value="3">three</option>
 <option value="4">four</option>
 <option value="5">five</option>
 <option value="6">six</option>
</select>

<input type="submit" onClick="myFunction();" value="Generate" />
```

Comment: See my answer below and see if that helped.

Comment: There is no need for `select.options[select.selectedIndex].value` in modern browsers (anything after NN4), `select.value` will do.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting `undefined` due to the fact that `Result` Has not been defined yet. Here are the changes you might need to make.

Since you are evaluating using `===` you need to set the `order` variable to `int`

```
var order = parseInt(select.options[select.selectedIndex].value);
```

Next, move `x.innerHTML = Result` to the bottom.

Here is the end result (with a little tidying) :

```
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("result");
    var listOne = Array();
    var listTwo = Array();
    var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * listOne.length);
    var letter = Math.floor(Math.random() * listTwo.length);
    var select = document.getElementById("mySelect");
    // casting it as an int. 
    // an alternative would be var order = +select.options[select.selectedIndex].value
    var order = parseInt(select.options[select.selectedIndex].value);

    var Result;

    listOne[0] = "1";
    listOne[1] = "2";
    listOne[2] = "3";

    listTwo[0] = "A";
    listTwo[1] = "B";
    listTwo[2] = "C";

    if (order === 1) {
        Result = listOne[number] + listTwo[letter] + listOne[number];

    }

    if (order === 2) {
        Result = listTwo[letter] + listOne[number] + listTwo[letter];
    }

    if (order === 3) {
        Result = listOne[number] + listTwo[letter] + listTwo[letter];
    }

    if (order === 4) {
        Result = listTwo[letter] + listOne[number] + listOne[number];
    }

    if (order === 5) {
        Result = listOne[number] + listOne[number] + listTwo[letter];
    }

    if (order === 6) {
        Result = listTwo[letter] + listTwo[letter] + listOne[number];
    }

    // add html AFTER Result has been set
    x.innerHTML = Result
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/rureye/2/edit)**

Give your submit button just an ID `#submit`

```
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="Generate" />
```

and this is all you need:

```
function myFunction(){

    var $result = document.getElementById("result");
    var $select = document.getElementById("mySelect"); 
    var order = $select.options[$select.selectedIndex].value;
    var listOne = ["1","2","3"]; // now it has length
    var listTwo = ["A","B","C"];
    var randNum  = Math.floor ( Math.random() * listOne.length ); 
    var randChar = Math.floor ( Math.random() * listTwo.length );
    var res = "";
    if (order === "1"){
      res = listOne[randNum] + listTwo[randChar] + listOne[randNum];
    }
    if (order === "2"){
      res = listTwo[randChar] + listOne[randNum] + listTwo[randChar];
    }
    if (order === "3"){
      res = listOne[randNum] + listTwo[randChar] + listTwo[randChar];
    }
    if (order === "4"){
      res = listTwo[randChar] + listOne[randNum] + listOne[randNum];
    }
    if (order === "5"){
      res = listOne[randNum] + listOne[randNum] + listTwo[randChar];
    }
    if (order === "6"){
      res = listTwo[randChar] + listTwo[randChar] + listOne[randNum];
    }  
    $result.innerHTML = res;
}

document.getElementById("submit").onclick = myFunction;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

**Working demo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GMce6/)**

HTML:

```
<div id="result"><i>Your result will appear here</i></div>
<form name="myform">
<select id="mySelect">
 <option value="1">one</option>
 <option value="2">two</option>
 <option value="3">three</option>
 <option value="4">four</option>
 <option value="5">five</option>
 <option value="6">six</option>
</select>

<input id="calc" type="button" value="Generate" />
</form>

function myFunction() {
    var x=document.getElementById("result");
    var listOne = [1, 2, 3];
    var listTwo = ["A", "B", "C"];

    var select = document.getElementById("mySelect");
    var order = +(select.options[select.selectedIndex].value);

    var number = Math.floor ( Math.random() * listOne.length ); 
    var letter = Math.floor ( Math.random() * listTwo.length );
    var result;

    if (order == 1) {
        result = listOne[number] + listTwo[letter] + listOne[number];
    }

    if (order === 2) {
        result = listTwo[letter] + listOne[number] + listTwo[letter];
    }

    if (order === 3) {
        result = listOne[number] + listTwo[letter] + listTwo[letter];
    }

    if (order === 4) {
        result = listTwo[letter] + listOne[number] + listOne[number];
    }

    if (order === 5) {
        result = listOne[number] + listOne[number] + listTwo[letter];
    }

    if (order === 6) {
        result = listTwo[letter] + listTwo[letter] + listOne[number];
    }

    x.innerHTML = result;

}

//Call the function;
document.getElementById("calc").onclick = myFunction;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make the value of the option elements a string like `'nln'` to represent the sequence 'number letter number'.

The function can be something like:

```
function getRandomString(s) {
  var a;
  var t = '';
  var data = {n: [0,1,2,3], l: ['a','b','c','d']};
  s = s.split('');

  for (var i=0, iLen=s.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    a = data[s[i]];
    t += a[Math.random()*a.length | 0];
  }
  return t;
}
```

The above may repeat values in the "random" string. To get unique values, use *splice* to get the value from the array instead of plain property access:

```
    t += a.splice(Math.random()*a.length | 0, 1);
```

The HTML can be like:

```
<form onsubmit="document.getElementById('result').innerHTML=getRandomString(this.mySelect.value);return false;">
  <select id=mySelect>
    <option value="nln" selected>one</option>
    <option value="lnl">two</option>
    <option value="nll">three</option>
    <option value="lnn">four</option>
    <option value="nnl">five</option>
    <option value="lln">six</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit"value="Generate">
</form>
<div><span id="result"></span></div>
```